# Is it possible to call multiple command handlers, when a command is dispatched in laravel

Tags: events, laravel, command

I have to call multiple commands handlers when a command is dispatched, I know we can use Events to handle multiple event handlers.

I want to whether it is possible to have multiple command handlers for a command in Laravel.

Comment: A command can be passed through one or many handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the laravel docs...

> **Calling Other Commands**
>
> Sometimes you may wish to call other commands from your command. You may do so using the call method:

```
$this->call('command:name', ['argument' => 'foo', '--option' => 'bar']);
```